# QT Duda graficando camino de puntos

Tags: c++, qt

Recibo posiciones en el plano y quiero dibujar el recorrido. No es una linea, sino un camino...es decir, yo recibo cada punto y genero un polígono que tiene un "ancho de labor" de 7, entonces cada punto que recibo, genero un polígono de 7 de ancho y los voy uniendo. Este es el codigo que generé:

```
void WorkedPathGraph::addPointToDraw(QPointF point)
{
    if (points.count() == 0)
        points.append(point);
    else
    {
        QPointF lastIns = points.last();
        QLineF aux1;
        aux1.setP1(lastIns);
        aux1.setP2(point);
        aux1.setLength(_anchoLabor / 2);
        aux1 = aux1.normalVector();

        QLineF lpt1;
        lpt1.setP1(aux1.p2());
        lpt1.setP2(aux1.p1());
        lpt1.setLength(_anchoLabor);

        QLineF aux2;
        aux2.setP1(point);
        aux2.setP2(lastIns);
        aux2.setLength(_anchoLabor / 2);
        aux2 = aux2.normalVector();

        QLineF lpt2;
        lpt2.setP1(aux2.p2());
        lpt2.setP2(aux2.p1());
        lpt2.setLength(_anchoLabor);

        QPolygonF newPol = QPolygonF(QVector<QPointF>() << lpt1.p1() << 
                 lpt1.p2() << lpt2.p1() << lpt2.p2());

        areas.append(newPol);
        path.addPolygon(newPol);

        points.append(point);
    }
    this->parentItem()->update();
}
```

Lo que hago ahi es tomar el punto que recibo y me ayudo con el anterior de forma que si se movió hacia un costado, tomo la perpendicular a la linea que genera ese punto con el anterior para generar el polígono. 
TODOS esos polígonos, los inserto en un `QPainterPath` y los dibujo...PERO el gráfico sale cortado...necesitaria que salga prolijo y las curvas mas CURVAS. Les dejo una imagen de como queda a ver si alguien me puede orientar a mejorarlo.

- `areas` es un `QVector<QPolygonF>`, que lo utilizo para ir acumulando los polígonos y sumar el área que va cubriendo la máquina.
- `points` es un `QVector<QPointF>`, que voy acumulando los puntos que recibo para generar los polígonos entre el punto que recibo y el ultimo que está almacenado en `points`.
- `path` es un `QPainterPath` que ahí le tiro todos los poligonos a pintar.

En el método PAINT lo que hago es:

```
void WorkedPathGraph::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *item, QWidget *widget)
{
    Q_UNUSED(widget);

    QPen qpen, qpenOld;
    QBrush oldBrush;
    qpen.setColor(QColor(0, 255, 0, 128));

    qpen.setWidth(1);
    qpen.setCosmetic(true);

    qpenOld = painter->pen();
    oldBrush = painter->brush();
    painter->setPen(qpen);

    painter->setClipRect(item->exposedRect);
    painter->setBrush(QColor(0,255,0, 128));

    painter->drawPath(path.simplified());
    painter->setPen(qpenOld);
   painter->setBrush(oldBrush);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que quedara algo al estilo este (No tiene la misma forma porque la hice en paint):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es `areas`? ¿y `path`? ¿y `points`? ¿Cual de todos es el que estás pintando? ¿Cómo lo pintas?

Comment: Puedes añadir una imagen que describa como debería ser la solución correcta?

Comment: Ahi lo edité para agregar la info que pides @eferion

Comment: @David, ahi subí una imagen similar a lo que deseo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los polígonos son independientes entre sí. Si lo que quieres es que el trazo sea contínuo tienes que dibujar la ruta punto a punto:

```
void WorkedPathGraph::addPointToDraw(QPointF point)
{
    if (points.count() == 0)
    {
        points.append(point);
        path.moveTo(point); // <<---
    }
    else
    {
        QPointF lastIns = points.last();
        QLineF aux1;
        aux1.setP1(lastIns);
        aux1.setP2(point);
        aux1.setLength(_anchoLabor / 2);
        aux1 = aux1.normalVector();

        QLineF lpt1;
        lpt1.setP1(aux1.p2());
        lpt1.setP2(aux1.p1());
        lpt1.setLength(_anchoLabor);

        QLineF aux2;
        aux2.setP1(point);
        aux2.setP2(lastIns);
        aux2.setLength(_anchoLabor / 2);
        aux2 = aux2.normalVector();

        QLineF lpt2;
        lpt2.setP1(aux2.p2());
        lpt2.setP2(aux2.p1());
        lpt2.setLength(_anchoLabor);

        QPolygonF newPol = QPolygonF(QVector<QPointF>() << lpt1.p1() << 
                 lpt1.p2() << lpt2.p1() << lpt2.p2());

        areas.append(newPol);
        // path.addPolygon(newPol);
        path.lineTo(point);    // <<---

        points.append(point);
    }
    this->parentItem()->update();
}
```

Comment: path.lineTo debe recibir un punto segun me indica el compilador. No me sirve que arme una linea finita...necesito unir poligonos (o algo que le dé la forma) para que dibuje el recorrido y el ancho de la maquina

Comment: @EmilianoTorres perdona, no puedo probar el código porque no tengo un ejemplo mínimo compilable... debería ser `point` en vez de `lpt2`

Comment: No me refería al error de compilacion...si bien no funciona, me referia a que poniendo solo puntos va a generar una linea finitia y no es la idea. Incluso con los puntos de tu idea, genera un poligono desde el margen hasta esa linea de puntos...Incluso, lo que necesitaria es que los cortes entre puntos, no se vean cortes bruscos sino curvas como la imagen del paint...no es sencillo lo que pido...llevo varias semanas intentandoló...ha ido mejorando pero aun asi no queda estético

Comment: @EmilianoTorres lo que pretenden hacer mis cambios es generar una gráfica con los puntos que tu le indicas. Si tu le das 3 puntos a la función el código generará la ruta `A-B` y `B-C` (dos rectas)

Comment: @EmilianoTorres en cuanto a lo de suavizar los cortes... estás trabajando con valores discretos luego no tienes forma de saber qué valores había entre el punto A y el punto B porque no tienes esa información... cualquier curva que quieras poner ahí es falsear los resultados. Tu función solo existe en el intervalo discreto en el cual tienes valores y ese intervalo viene dado por los puntos que le facilitas al objeto... fuera de esos puntos tu función no existe

Comment: lo de suavizar se entiende y es correcto lo que me comentas. Con respecto a la generacion de la grafica, el lineTo no me sirve...porque estoy graficando una linea entre puntos...lo mismo que haria si le digo "painter->drawLine(points);"...yo necesito generar ese "camino" pero que sea continuo, sin los "recortes" que se ven en la imagen y que tenga un ancho dado...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76970/discussion-between-eferion-and-emiliano-torres).